# FVS336G PPP SNMP monitoring

Tags: snmp, point-to-point-protocol, netgear

Using SNMP to monitor a [Netgear FVS336G](http://www.netgear.com.au/au/Product/VPN-Firewalls/Wired-VPN-Firewalls/FVS336G), I can access all of the interfaces statistics except for PPP1. We have two PPP connections but SNMP only reveals:

```
ifDescr1    03 May 2011 08:52:16    "lo"
ifDescr2    03 May 2011 08:52:26    "eth0"
ifDescr3    03 May 2011 08:52:38    "eth0.2"
ifDescr4    03 May 2011 08:51:50    "eth0.3"
ifDescr5    03 May 2011 08:52:03    "eth0.4"
ifDescr6    03 May 2011 08:52:03    "ppp0"
```

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas how I can monitor both PPP connections? There is, as far as I can tell, no specific MIBs for an FVS336G.

Comment: Insert generic snide netgear-hating comment here. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the ifdescr table doesn't show it, it's either not supported or it's a bug.  I can't find anything searching the netgear site, so it might be worthwhile to open up a support ticket with them asking about it.